# Sympy - How to allow free variables in solver

Tags: python, sympy

I've been using sympy as an algebra solver and was trying to have it solve for situations where I want to maintain a variable as free. As a simplified example, i'd like it to solve: y = A*x^2 + B*x + C and y = 1*x^2 + 2*x + 3 in terms of A, B, and C for all values of x or all values of x within an interval.

I know how to specify ignoring a variable, but is there a way to specify that it can be any value? At the moment, I add equations by substituting values of x to close the d.o.f., but this is less than ideal when scaling up from this simplified example. It also solves for a bunch of useless variables.

```py
# imports
import sympy
A,B,C,x,y = sympy.symbols('A,B,C,x,y')

# definitions
give = []
want = [A,B,C]
free = [x]
eqs = [sympy.Eq( y , A*x**2 + B*x + C ),
       sympy.Eq( y , 1*x**2 + 2*x + 3 )]

# get total symbol list
free_symbols = set()
for eq in eqs: free_symbols.update(eq.free_symbols)

# get symbols that are not of the prior listings
other = free_symbols - set(want) - set(free)

# get the number of missing dof
missing_dof = len(free_symbols)-len(eqs)

# increase equations to bring dof to zero
new_eqs = []
for i in range(missing_dof):
    
    # set free variable to i
    subs = {sym:i for sym in free}
    
    # rename other variables so equations stay consitant
    subs.update({sym:sympy.Symbol(f'{sym}_{i}') for sym in other})
    
    # substitute the new values
    new_eqs.extend([eq.subs(subs) for eq in eqs])

# actually solve
ans = sympy.solve(new_eqs,dict=True)
print({k:v for k,v in ans[0].items() if k in want})
```

{A: 1, B: 2, C: 3}

Comment: In the case of transcendental functions like:

 Eq(A*sin(x) + B*cos(x), cos(x))

I got better results by, instead of evaluating `x`, differentiating and replacing `x` at 0.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want `solve_undetermined_coeffs` e.g.:

```
In [11]: A,B,C,x,y = sympy.symbols('A,B,C,x,y')

In [12]: pattern = A*x**2 + B*x + C

In [13]: equation = x**2 + 2*x + 3

In [14]: eq = Eq(pattern, equation)

In [15]: eq
Out[15]: 
   2              2          
A⋅x  + B⋅x + C = x  + 2⋅x + 3

In [16]: solve_undetermined_coeffs(eq, [A, B, C], x)
Out[16]: {A: 1, B: 2, C: 3}
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.solve_undetermined_coeffs

Simple examples like the one shown can also be solved more efficiently using pattern matching using `Wild` and `match`:

```
In [22]: A, B, C = symbols('A:C', cls=Wild, exclude=[x])

In [23]: x = Symbol('x')

In [24]: (x**2 + 2*x + 3).match(A*x**2 + B*x + C)
Out[24]: {A: 1, B: 2, C: 3}
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.match

Comment: Thank you for the follow up. While, those would certainly be cleaner to implement in clean examples, they don't work as well for the complex ones I had in mind.

Comment: Saying simply "they don't work as well" doesn't leave any scope for me to offer something better.

Comment: Apologies you are completely right about that.  Your example works well if I am matching two clearly similar equations. I would like to be able to solve a larger set of intermingled equations where it's not trivial to find (or substitute to create) the matching equations.  That is why I was hoping to find a way to specify x as an undetermined symbol. (My equations are also not always only polynomials)

Comment: There is not a general way to express `x` as an "undetermined symbol". I think that you should show a more complicated problem to be solved if the above does not work. For the general class of problems that you have what approach would you take if you were working on pen and paper?